# Axis2C Staff REST login service

Tags: rest, web-services, axis2c, staff-wsf

I'm using Axis2/C unofficial with the Staff project to simply expone a set of methods to return a dataset with the REST paradigm.

Now I need to authenticate users and I want to use the "staff.Login" built in service of Staff, always in REST methods.

I am able to call the "login" and "openSession" methods (they both return me a valid sessionID), but I cannot mantain this session on following calls because if I afterwards call the method "getUserName" it says i'm a guest user and not the user i authenticated before!

Do I have to pass the session ID on every following call to the service like a token?
Can someone link me any documentation or example about the login service? (I can't find much on the net)

Thanks.

PS: Staff has a sample client for testing this service, and it runs correctly, but I need to use the service from a browser with REST methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using REST+JSON, your request could be like that:

```
{
  "@headers": {
    "SessionId":"SID"
  },
  "GetUserName": {}
}
```

If you're using REST+SOAP, your request could be like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <sid:SessionId xmlns:sid="http://tempui.org/staff/sessionid">SID</sid:SessionId>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns0:GetUserName xmlns:ns0="http://tempui.org/staff.Login"/>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Where `SID` is a session ID returned by "openSession" or "login".

Comment: Thank you, it works. And how to send session id when doing a GET request? Is it possible?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible

Comment: It would be nice to send in a header... Keep in mind for future development ;)